# optimize multiplication by using for loop supposing multiplication is slower than addition

Tags: optimization

If multiplication is slower than addition instead of doing

```
7 * 8
```

Will this theoretically improve performance ?

```
for(int i =0; i < 8 ; i++){
temp += 7
}
```

Or else do i just need to do

```
7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 7
```

Comment: Under which circumstances and which hardware is multiplication supposedly slower than addition? Most reasonably modern processors have built-in multiplication instructions that are close to addition speed-wise.

Comment: Any language / platform in mind ?

Comment: I mean suppose multiplication is slower than addition then how should i attempt to improve it ?

Comment: This code will fail if the 2nd term is negative.

Comment: `7 << 3` will be faster; too bad the compiler will likely do it for you already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried it and timed it?

On nearly every single modern machine today, there is fast hardware support for multiplication. So unless it's simple multiplication by 2, **no, it will not be faster**.

To give some hard numbers on the current Intel machines:

```
add/sub   1 cycle latency
mul/imul  3 cycle latency
```

Taken from [Agner Fog's manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf).

Although it's actually a lot more complicated than this, the point is still: *No, you're not going to get any benefit trying to replace multiplications with additions.*

In the few cases where it *is* better (such as multiplication by a power of two - using shifts), the compiler will make that optimization for you, if it knows the value at compile-time.

On x86, the compiler can also play with the `lea` instruction to do fast multiplication by 3, 5, 10, etc...

Comment: Yeah the compiler will produce the optimal code for that stuff anyhow. Afaik there are several CPUs where the compiler will replace `a*2` with `a+a` though instead of `a >> 1` so there's some truth here. But that's obviously a special case - still fun seeing all the people writing `a >> 1` to "optimize" their code though.

Comment: @Voo I think in all the cases I see now, the compiler does actually do `a+a` instead of `a>>1`. And this does make sense since additions/subtractions have been so heavily optimized over the years to the point that they often have a higher throughput than shifts.

Comment: Oops, mea culpa, you're right ;-) And yes it does make sense that addition is more heavily optimized than shifts - I just didn't want to make any definite statements without having it actually tested for several CPUs or some other "proof". But looking at Aigner's manuals a bit, the reciprocal throughput is generally higher for adds than shifts, so there we are. Another situation where intuition is rather misleading and compiler writers figure the right thing out for one.

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to believe that 16 value assignments, 16 additions, and 8 conditional statements are faster than the processior can multiply 7*8.

Comment: i used 7 * 8 so that i could write the question easily. What if 8 is something like 15111 ? Then you will definitely see some lag in my case.

Comment: You would see much higher latency in a for loop that large, than in one multiplication statement. A modern processor will multiply 7*8 at the same speed that it will multiply 7*15111. A for loop is accessing memory and moving things around in the registers too many times to be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on architecture. But, generally loops are a lot slower than a single native code (especially due to branches). Intel CPUs have a good implementation of multiplication, thus usually outperform AMD and other CPUs. You can have look at CPU's characteristics [here](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf). Also, you can use that [program](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#testp) to precisely measure your piece of code speed.

If you really concern about speed, sometimes you can approximate multiplication or division. Most notable trick for multiplication could be bit-shift or lookup table. e.g. if you want to multiply a number with a power-of-2 number you can just use shift instruction.

If you need something more better, you can change number's domain e.g. logistic domain with a quantized table. And in that case multiplication becomes addition i.e. `log(A*B) = log(A)+log(B)`.

These kind of tricks are usually used in data compression to estimate bit probabilities or implement approximate arithmetic coders.